# Limit of composition of non-continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Assume $f$ and $g$ are defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ and $lim_{x\to p} f(x) = q$ and $lim_{x\to q} g(x) = r$. Give an example to show that it may not be true that $$lim_{x\to p} g(f(x)) = r$$

I've toyed with various ideas, including Dirichlet's and Thomae's functions, but I can't seem to come up with an example.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take $f(x)$ to be constant, and remember that $\lim_{x\to q}g(x)$ doesn't depend on $g(q)$.